# Oracle Weblogic 10.3.5 Cluster creation issues

Tags: cluster, installation, weblogic, unicast

I'm trying to create a two node cluster with Oracle Weblogic 10.3.5. During the "Fusion Middleware Configuration Wizard" setup process, I'm not sure what to put in for the "Cluster Address" if I choose "unicast" cluster messaging mode.

Also the second node resides on another machine. How do I go about creating and adding the node on the remote machine to this cluster? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "ClusterAddress" should be Hostname and port number of the two nodes separated by a comma.

for ex:  Localhost:8001,localhost:8003

If want to add a remote node into the cluster, you would need to create a machine , start a node manager on the remote physical machine, enroll the nodemananger. Then you would need to create a managed node with the remote server hostname.

You can follow the below link for creating a distributed cluster setup.

http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2013/09/01/weblogic-server-distributed-setup

Answer (score -1):

Cluster settings can be modified after installation so if this is a completely fresh environment, then what to set that to is not an immediate concern. ***If no channel is specified, then a default is used.***

The cluster address can be either a DNS host name which maps to multiple IP addresses, or a list of host names or IPs separated by commas.

As for your second question, [there's a blog post here](http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2010/10/configuring-and-testing-weblogic.html) which tells you how to go about setting up a cluster in Weblogic, though some of the images are broken. [There's an updated version here](http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2012/10/basic-clustering-with-weblogic-12c-and.html) for Weblogic 12c.